# Calculating the difference in dates in a Pandas GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following format:

```
In [0]: df
Out[0]: 
       col1  col2       date
 0     1     1          2015-01-01
 1     1     2          2015-01-09
 2     1     3          2015-01-10
 3     2     1          2015-02-10
 4     2     2          2015-02-10
 5     2     3          2015-02-25

In [1]: df.dtypes
Out[1]:
 col1             int64
 col2             int64
 date    datetime64[ns]
 dtype: object
```

We want to find the value for `col2` corresponding to the greatest difference in date (between consecutive elements in the sorted-by-dates groups), grouped by `col1`. Assume there are no groups of size 1.

**Desired Output**

```
In [2]: output
Out[2]:
col1   col2
1      1         # This is because the difference between 2015-01-09 and 2015-01-01 is the greatest
2      2         # This is because the difference between 2015-02-25 and 2015-02-10 is the greatest
```

The real `df` has many values for `col1` that we need to groupby to do calculations.  Is this possible by applying a function to the following?  Please note, the dates are already in ascending order.

```
gb = df.groupby(col1)
gb.apply(right_maximum_date_difference)
```

Comment: So, as I noted in my answer, I think you have a mistake in the question: "2015-01-09 - 2015-01-01" is *not* the greatest.

Comment: The difference between 2015-01-09 and 2015-01-01 is 8 days.  The difference between 2015-01-10 and 2015-01-09 is 1 day.  In this case, I am interested in capturing the value of `col2` corresponding to the date of 2015-01-01 since the difference is the greatest.

Comment: Oh, so you mean with the previous row in the same groupby. I have to say that is extremely unclear from the question. Also, it is undefined groups of size 1.

Comment: This operation will only apply to groups that are larger that 2 in the original dataframe.

Comment: Well, updated both the question & answer to reflect this. I must say that I think the phrasing could have been improved, esp. as the undefined result in the case of length=1 groups was not made explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that's almost your dataframe (I avoided copying the dates):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'date': [1, 9, 10, 10, 10, 25]
})
```

With this, define:

```
def max_diff_date(g):
    g = g.sort(columns=['date'])
    return g.col2.ix[(g.date.ix[1: ] - g.date.shift(1)).argmax() - 1]
```

and you have:

```
>> df.groupby(df.col1).apply(max_diff_date)
col1
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The `lambda` function you wrote will find the **maximum date** and return the value for `col2` corresponding to that date.  This is not what we want (if I wanted that, I could just look up the last row in each groupby since the dates are already ordered).  **I need to do a between row operation to find the difference in dates, and take the maximum of those to find the value of `col2`.**

Comment: The previous comment by me is outdated, the code has been changed since then.

Ami, I think you did it!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ami, I'm having a bunch of trouble getting this to work for DateTime types.  Can you help?  It works great for integers but that is just one step for me.

Comment: @invoker Yeah, I'll have a look.

Comment: @invoker I ran the exact same code on the DataFrame of JoeCondron's answer below, and it worked exactly the same. So the problem is in the step between your type of DataFrame and that one. Here's a suggestion: open a new question on that. This site is really not built for dialogs in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I would try a slightly differnt tack: Pivot the table so that you have a column for each value in `col2` containing the dates and the values of `col1` as the index. Then you can use the `.diff` method to get the differences between consecutive cells. This might not work if there are duplicate `col1`, `col2` pairs though, which is not clear from the question.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
          'col2': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
          'date': pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10', 
                                  '2015-02-10', '2015-02-10', '2015-02-25'])})
p = df.pivot(columns='col1', index='col2', values='date')
p
    col1    1   2
col2        
1   2015-01-01  2015-02-10
2   2015-01-09  2015-02-10
3   2015-01-10  2015-02-25

p.diff().shift(-1).idxmax() 

col1
1       1
2       2
```

The `.shift(-1)` takes care of the fact that you want the first of the two  consecutive dates with the largest difference.