# split, groupby, combine in Pandas to find a difference in dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to use `groupby` to group by id, then find some way to difference the dates, and then column bind them back to the dataframe, so I end up with this:

[image]

The groupby is straightforward,

```
grouped = DF.groupby('id')
```

and finding the earliest date is straightforward,

```
maxdates = grouped['date'].min()
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed. How do I apply the date subtraction operation, then combine?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716123/calculating-the-difference-in-dates-in-a-pandas-groupby-object).

Thanks for reading this far.

My dataframe is:

```
dates=pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05'])

DF = DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'date':dates})
cols = ['id', 'date']
DF=DF[cols]
```

**EDIT:**
Both answers below are awesome. I wish I could accept them both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use apply like this:

```
earliest_by_id = DF.groupby('id')['date'].min()
def since_earliest(row):
    return row.date - earliest_by_id[row.id]

DF['days_since_earliest'] = DF.apply(since_earliest, axis=1)
print(DF)
```

---

```
   id       date  days_since_earliest
0   1 2015-01-01               0 days
1   1 2015-02-01              31 days
2   1 2015-03-01              59 days
3   1 2015-04-01              90 days
4   1 2015-05-01             120 days
5   2 2015-01-01               0 days
6   2 2015-01-02               1 days
7   2 2015-01-03               2 days
8   2 2015-01-04               3 days
9   2 2015-01-05               4 days
```

**edit:**

```
DF['days_since_earliest'] = DF.apply(since_earliest, axis=1).astype('timedelta64[D]')
print(DF)

   id       date  days_since_earliest
0   1 2015-01-01                    0
1   1 2015-02-01                   31
2   1 2015-03-01                   59
3   1 2015-04-01                   90
4   1 2015-05-01                  120
5   2 2015-01-01                    0
6   2 2015-01-02                    1
7   2 2015-01-03                    2
8   2 2015-01-04                    3
9   2 2015-01-05                    4
```

Comment: Pandas is so amazing. That APL heritage FTW!

Comment: @DTing I didn't know that `DF.date` and `DF["date"]` were synonymous. Indexing in Pandas is a wild ride, what with `[ ], .ix, .loc. .iloc` etc etc. I guess I will add `.` to the list.

Also -- why does this function return `x days`? How do we get rid of it the text `days`? Seems quite presumptuous of Pandas to inject text in there like that.  Actually, an equally pressing question would be, how did the operation return the value in days to begin with? Why was it not, say, years, or months? Very mysterious stuff going on here...

Comment: The `days_since_earliest`  has a dtype of `timedelta64[ns]`. You can convert using: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, using [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) can often be simpler (and usually faster) than `apply`.  `transform` takes the results of a groupby operation and broadcasts it up to the original index:

```
>>> df["dse"] = df["date"] - df.groupby("id")["date"].transform(min)
>>> df
   id       date      dse
0   1 2015-01-01   0 days
1   1 2015-02-01  31 days
2   1 2015-03-01  59 days
3   1 2015-04-01  90 days
4   1 2015-05-01 120 days
5   2 2015-01-01   0 days
6   2 2015-01-02   1 days
7   2 2015-01-03   2 days
8   2 2015-01-04   3 days
9   2 2015-01-05   4 days
```

If you'd prefer integer days instead of timedelta objects, you can use the `dt.days` accessor:

```
>>> df["dse"] = df["dse"].dt.days
>>> df
   id       date  dse
0   1 2015-01-01    0
1   1 2015-02-01   31
2   1 2015-03-01   59
3   1 2015-04-01   90
4   1 2015-05-01  120
5   2 2015-01-01    0
6   2 2015-01-02    1
7   2 2015-01-03    2
8   2 2015-01-04    3
9   2 2015-01-05    4
```