# Pandas groupby mark dates less than n months

Tags: python, pandas

So in this example, col1 has 2 different categories. How would one be able to compute those categories that satisfy if we say n months = 12, so that a new column would mark category A as True, but cat B as false since it is greater than n=12 months.

```
d_ex = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                     'col2': ['2019-01-01', '2018-02-01',
                             '2015-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-05-01']})

d_ex['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(d_ex['col2'])
```

I tried

```
d_ex.groupby(['col1'])['col2'].diff()
```

but this does not work. Also there can be more than **two occurences** of the category, so if there was a third category A with a date of 2015, I would like that marked as False but the other two still true.

I found this but I am not sure how to change the code to not use idxmax
[Calculating the difference in dates in a Pandas GroupBy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716123/calculating-the-difference-in-dates-in-a-pandas-groupby-object)

Trying the solution given

```
(d_ex.groupby('col1')['col2'].diff().apply(lambda x: my_abs(x))
.apply(lambda x: set_condition(x)).bfill())
```

returns

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
```

but index 4 should be True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Create the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

d_ex = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                     'col2': ['2019-01-01', '2018-02-01',
                              '2015-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-05-01']})

d_ex['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(d_ex['col2'])

# Sort the columns
d_ex.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'], inplace=True)

col1       col2
   A 2018-02-01
   A 2019-01-01
   A 2019-05-01
   B 2015-01-01
   B 2019-01-01
```

#### Groupby Diff:

- `diff` returns a `timedelta` object for each group

  - `NaT` always for the first occurrence within a group

```py
d_ex['diff'] = d_ex.groupby('col1').diff()

col1       col2      diff
   A 2018-02-01       NaT
   A 2019-01-01  334 days
   A 2019-05-01  120 days
   B 2015-01-01       NaT
   B 2019-01-01 1461 days
```

#### Function to return abs of diff

- `abs` doesn't work on `NaT`, so `abs` can't just be applied
- If you use `sort_values` on `col1` and `col2`, this step can be skipped

```py
def my_abs(x):
    try:
        x = abs(x)
    except TypeError:
        x = x
    return x

# Apply the function
d_ex['diff'] = d_ex['diff'].apply(lambda x: my_abs(x))

col1       col2      diff
   A 2018-02-01       NaT
   A 2019-01-01  334 days
   A 2019-05-01  120 days
   B 2015-01-01       NaT
   B 2019-01-01 1461 days
```

#### A Function to set the condition, None if NaT

- Because of using `groupby` and `diff`, the first row of any group, should be NaT
- Set `NaT` to None, then it can be `backfilled`

```py
def set_condition(x):
    if type(x) == pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType:
        x = None
    elif x <= pd.Timedelta('365 days'):
        x = True
    else:
        x = False
    return x

# Apply the function
d_ex['condition'] = d_ex['diff'].apply(lambda x: set_condition(x))

col1       col2      diff condition
   A 2018-02-01       NaT      None
   A 2019-01-01  334 days      True
   A 2019-05-01  120 days      True
   B 2015-01-01       NaT      None
   B 2019-01-01 1461 days     False
```

#### Backfill None:

```py
d_ex.condition.bfill(inplace=True)

col1       col2      diff  condition
   A 2018-02-01       NaT       True
   A 2019-01-01  334 days       True
   A 2019-05-01  120 days       True
   B 2015-01-01       NaT      False
   B 2019-01-01 1461 days      False
```

Comment: @bbd108 The answer has been updated to sort `col1` and `col2`. This also removes the need to use `my_abs`.